# SPListItemCollection GetDataTable bug

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I'm using SPListItemCollection.GetDataTable to return the list search results. The GetDataTable doesn't contain all the columns that are mentioned in ViewFields, but I can see all those columns in SPListItemCollection.Xml property. Columns like AverageRating are missing. Is this a known issue?

I'm using datatable for doing some filtering and row operations on the returned result as it is easier to do with a datatable. Now I'm planning to create dataset from SPListItemCollection.Xml and return the datatable from there. Is there a better approach?

Thanks

Comment: plz post your code so i'll you provide perfect solution..

Comment: Code is like below..I have tested by writing the items.Xml and items.GetDataTable to an xml file. I can see that xml returned by GetDataTable doesn't contain the rating columns.                                         SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(spQuery)               return items.GetDataTable();

Comment: I think also that the columns are not selected in the query.

Answer (score 1):

try this code...
it'll work perfectly in my system.

```
  SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
  query.Query = string.Concat(
                            "<Where><Eq>",
                            "<FieldRef Name='Status'/>",
                            "<Value Type='CHOICE'>Not Started</Value>",
                            "</Eq></Where>");

  query.ViewFields = string.Concat(
                                  "<FieldRef Name='Title' />",
                                  "<FieldRef Name='StartDate' />",
                                  "<FieldRef Name='DueDate' />",
                                  "<FieldRef Name='Priority' />");

  query.ViewFieldsOnly = true; 


   SPListItemCollection oItem = splist.GetItems(query);
   DataTable objDatatable =   oItem.GetDataTable();
```

plz dont forget to apply **query.ViewFieldsOnly = true;**

Hope it helps.... :D